# Gdbserver, remote debugging, printf() output not seen on the host

Tags: c, linux, gdb, gdbserver

I am running gdbserver on a remote armv5 target with the following command line:

```
./gdbserver --debug --remote-debug --multi :9000
```

The host machine is x86 Linux. I am trying to remote-debug a sample hello_world.c program, pretty much a  int main(int argc, char** argv) { printf("hello world\n"); exit(0); };

I am doing the following on the host machine:

```
./gdb
(gdb)set sysroot /home/username
(gdb)set verbose on
(gdb)target extended-remote 192.168.1.217:9000
(gdb)file hello_world
(gdb)set remote exec-file /upgrade/hello_world
(gdb)r
```

The output is as follows:

```
    Starting program: /home/username/hello_world

Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.3.so
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.6.so
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0xbe90cdd4) at hello_world.c:50
50         int parm=7;

    (gdb) c

        Continuing.
        [Inferior 1 (process 16721) exited normally]
```

Notice that there is no printf() output on the host machine. It just stops on a breakpoint and then runs to completion when I hit 'c'.

I expect the \n in the printf to flush the buffer and produce output immediately, but for some reason I do not see it in the host gdb window.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Why should there be any `printf` output on the host machine? The I/O is done on the target. `gdb` cannot and does not magically intercept it and deliver it to you.

Comment: Looks like you're correct, I saw the output on the target. Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Even though I am a bit disappointed :)